# Visual studio 2010 - setting up a class as startup object in my project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a new VB project(console application) in Visual Studio 2010 and added a new class(vb class) to the project.

Can the new class I added be used as a startup object in the project properties?

If yes, how? I can't see the new class I created in the startup object dropdown in project properties.

Is there any other way of setting up the class as startup object in the project properties startup object dropdown menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this but you will have to *move* your `Sub Main` into the class and declare it as  **Shared**:

```
 Shared Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Startup")
 End Sub
```

Then change the Startup Object to `Sub Main`

Comment: doing it this way you will get Sub Main is declared more than once.

Comment: You need to remove the original sub main

Comment: I face the same scenario, I want to point out one thing "Enable application framework" should be disable to select shared method from class or even class

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - you need to make your `Main` method in your class static, using the [`shared` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx):

```
Public Class AppStarter
    Shared Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Entry point")
    End Sub
End Class
```

This class will be visible in the project settings:

[image]

Another option would be to create a [*static module*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da.aspx) where your `Main` is placed and in this main function(sub) to use your custom class.

More information about how to do this (for console and GUI application), can be found in this [MSDN How to: Change the Startup object for an application (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/17k74w0c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: You can't enable application framework on a console app

Comment: @MattWilko, Fredou: changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

using this show the `Class1` in the dropdown

you can then select `Class1` as the startup

```
Public Class Class1

Public Shared Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Class
```